# Apply printsetup to specific worksheets based on cell values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a drop down box that i would like to use to apply a printsetup to specific sheets in my workbook.
Specifically, applying a footer that has page numbers on it. the drop box is a page numbers On/Off option

Beneath this is a list of worksheets in the workbook that have a tick box option to be hidden/not hidden.

The script i'm trying to write would deploy when the the drop down menu is changed and apply the specified printsetup to worksheets that have a tick in the hide/unhide cell column.

This is where i have got to;

Cell O20 is where my page numbers on/off drop down box is
Range O40:O282 is where the hide/unhide tick boxes are for each sheet in the list
The sheetnames are referenced in column J which is why im offseting the value (0, -5)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("O20")) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case UCase(Target.Value)
        Case "ON"
            Sheets(Cells(Range("O40:O282").Value(ChrW(&H2713)).Offset(0, -5))).Select
                PageSetup.RightFooter = "&""Arial,Regular""&8Page &P of &N"
        Case "OFF"
            Sheets(Cells(Range("O40:O282").Value(ChrW(&H2713)).Offset(0, -5))).Select
                PageSetup.RightFooter = ""
    End Select
    End If
```

My VBA knowledge is limited so if solutions could be as descriptive as possible this would be a massive help!

Comment: Is `drop down box` on cell `O20` a data validation or worksheet control?

Comment: O20 is a data validation

Answer (score 0):

- Assumes a data validation dropdown box is on `cell O20`

```vb
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$O$20" Then
        Dim c As Range, sPg As String
        Select Case UCase(Target.Value)
        Case "ON"
            For Each c In Me.Range("O40:JO282").Cells
                If c.Value = ChrW(&H2713) Then
                    sPg = "&""Arial,Regular""&8Page &P of &N"
                Else
                    sPg = ""
                End If
                Sheets(c.Offset(0, -5)).PageSetup.RightFooter = sPg
            Next
        Case "OFF"
            For Each c In Me.Range("O40:JO282").Offset(0, -5).Cells
                Sheets(c.Value).PageSetup.RightFooter = ""
            Next
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: getting a run time error 13 for Case "ON" part of script but Case "OFF" is working!

Comment: Which line raises a run time error 13?

Comment: Sheets(c.Offset(0, -5)).PageSetup.RightFooter = sPg triggered the runtime error

Comment: I don't see any error on it. Please try `Sheets(c.Offset(0, -5).Value).PageSetup.RightFooter = sPg`.